# C# WinForms - weird border

Tags: c#, winforms

i have weird border in my app. I user MetroFramework and when I run app i see:

[image: Weird border]

When I click in it, it disappears.

What is it? How i Can Delete this?

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: That framework suffers from lots of little quirks.  The project has been abandoned, updates and bug fixes ended 6 years ago.  Don't use it.

Comment: @hansPassant thank you for you info. Can you reccomended me someone?